# Cannot SSH into WD my book

Tags: ssh, users

The only two users on my NAS that I can SSH to are the defaults 'root' and 'admin'.
Answers that I've come across so far are like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98781/ssh-client-authentication-as-non-root-user), where I set things in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` like

```
AllowUser userName

PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

However there is no directory `/etc/ssh/` but I found the file `sshd_config` off of `/etc/`. I did the latter and I added in the 'AllowUser' because it wasn't there.  I rebooted and the issue persists.

- Are there different "flavors" of ssh?
- If so, where I can learn about the one I have?  (NAS shell doesn't have 'man')

I'm SSH'ing from Ubuntu 16.04 to a Western Digital MyBook model #WD10000H1NC-00
Please let me know if you need more info from me.

Comment: Well, if that directory doesn't exist, consider trying to create it

Comment: They could have configured sshd to use `/etc/sshd_config`, it is more likely than deleting the directory and leaving a file behind.  You need to look through the entire file, options like `PermitRootLogin no` or `PasswordAuthentication no` or even `UsePAM yes` will impact in the way `sshd` authenticates, no matter the value of `AllowUser`

Comment: Also, try changing it to `AllowUsers` in the `/etc/sshd_config`.

Comment: Do users other than root and admin have valid login shells?

Comment: The file may be at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or `/etc/sshd_config`, that depends on the distribution, edit the one that's already there. Copy-paste the complete content of the file. Which user are you trying to log in as, with what authentication method (password or key), and what errors do you get (copy-paste)?

Comment: On some embedded systems the entire root filesystem gets redeployed from a compressed image when it's rebooted. It would be worth checking that your changes are still present in the `/etc/sshd_config` file.

Comment: Did changing it to `AllowUsers` fix it, Samsquatch? Also, @roaima, for what it's worth, I checked on my WD My Cloud and the changes I make are still there on a reboot. That doesn't necessarily mean that's the case for WD My Books, though.

Comment: Actually, I don't know.  Among things I was trying, I upgraded the firmware.  Big mistake because now I have ZERO ssh access (even though it's enabled).  Some googling leads me to believe that it's a firmware issue, so now I'm trying to figure out how to downgrade...I appreciate your answer though, there's some good info there to study up on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try changing `AllowUser userName` in the `/etc/sshd_config` file on your WD My Book to `AllowUsers root admin userName` to see if that resolves the issue.

Also, check the contents of `/etc/passwd` and make sure that the entry for `userName` doesn't include `/user/sbin/nologin`, but instead something like `/bin/bash`. For instance, the entry for the admin account in my own WD MyCloud is this:

```
admin:x:999:1000::/shares:/bin/sh
```

Regarding learning more about the flavors of `ssh`, when starting the connection you can add the `-v` flag for verbose output (or even `-vvv` for more output if desired):

```
ssh -v root@WD_MyBook_IP
```

When I connect to my NAS I see the output below. This tells me that my local system uses `OpenSSH_6.6.1` and my NAS uses `OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3`.

```
ssh -v root@ip_address
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.20 [192.168.0.20] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
------------Truncated---------------
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3
```